# Driver with the Most Race Wins in a Single Season

Tags: formula-1, auto-racing

With Max Verstappen currently tearing up the F1 Championship by claiming his 9th race win of the season in Spa (BEL), only needs a handful of races to retain his F1 World Championship.

With 8 races remaining, he has the chance to rack up as many wins as possible, but who currently holds the record for the most wins in a single season.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time the question was asked, the record was **13 wins in a season**, held by two drivers: Michael Schumacher, who won 13 out of 18 races in 2004; and Sebastian Vettel, who won 13 out of 19 races in 2013.

Verstappen went on to win 15 races in 2022, and as of the time of this edit, has won **17 races** in 2023, breaking the record for a second time. Verstappen now also holds the record for highest *proportion* of races won in a season: 17/22 = 77.27%, breaking the record of 75% (6 wins in 8 races) set by Alberto Ascari in 1952. That proportion will increase to as high as 86.36% if he wins the remaining two races at Las Vegas and Abu Dhabi.